# Application of Dominated Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I need help with this problem:

> Suppose that $f$ is a Lebesgue integrable function defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Prove that
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|}dx \to \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)dx.$$

If I define $f_n(x) = f(x)e^{-\frac{1}{n}||x||}$, then I am having trouble finding a suitable integrable $\phi(x)$ such that $|f_n(x)| \le \phi(x)$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$0\leq e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|}\leq1$ so that $|f_n|=|f|e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|}\leq |f|$ and then you can use DCT.

Edit: We can also use MCT: First we have
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|}\,dx -\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)\,dx\right|\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)|(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|})\,dx.$$
Since $|f(x)|e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|}\nearrow|f(x)|$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$, an application of MCT to $|f(x)|e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|}$ gives that 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f(x)|e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|}\,dx\nearrow\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f(x)|\,dx$$
and therefore 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)|(1-e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|})\,dx\to0\ \ \text{as } n\to\infty,$$
so
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)e^{-\frac{1}{n}\|x\|}\,dx \to\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)\,dx\ \ \text{as } n\to\infty.$$
But unlike the other answer, my opinion is that it is easier to use DCT than MCT.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (in my opinion) is not to use dominated convergence, but rather [monotone convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi's_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral).

Comment: How exactly? We don't have $f \ge 0$.

Comment: @mechanodroid See my edited answer.